# What do you do with a comma that would come after a dash?

Tags: punctuation, commas, dashes

One common use of em dashes is to offset parenthetical phrases. But if a comma outside the parenthetical phrase immediately follows the parenthetical, what do you do with the comma?

I realize that that explanation is a little long-winded and confusing, so here's an example of a sentence that I'm unsure about (should there be a comma after the closing dash?):

> I am a man ― a strong, burly man ― but I cannot endorse your claim.

Without a parenthetical, it is straightforward; there is a comma:

> I am a man, but I cannot endorse your claim.

With parentheses, it is also straightforward; there is a comma:

> I am a man (a strong, burly man), but I cannot endorse your claim

**In the first example, what do you do with the comma after "man" that appears in the second example? Does you put it in a different place or cut it out entirely?** Should it be:

> I am a man ― a strong, burly man ― but I cannot endorse your claim. (No comma, as written above)
>
> I am a man, ― a strong, burly man ― but I cannot endorse your claim. (comma before the opening dash)
>
> I am a man ― a strong, burly man, ― but I cannot endorse your claim. (comma before the closing dash)
>
> I am a man ― a strong, burly man ―, but I cannot endorse your claim. (comma after the closing dash)

Comment: I'd first get rid of the comma after "burly".

Comment: But after that, a comma represents a pause, as does a dash.  You don't need two pauses.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Both of your example sentences look fine—and neither has both dashes and a comma after *man*. Nor do you use a sentence with parentheses. Can you add an example of the type of sentence you're not clear about?

Comment: @JasonBassford I edited it. Is it clearer now? What I mean is that if I were to write the first example, would I need a comma where the closing dash is?

Comment: @Maxwell I think I get where you're coming from—but in your second example you say, "without a parenthetical, it is straightforward; there is a comma." However, there ***isn't*** a comma. Either your description contains a typo, or you had *meant* to put a comma before *but* that didn't make its way there.

Comment: @JasonBassford Whoops, that was just a typo. I fixed it. Thank you for being able to read things, a skill which I evidently lack.

Comment: Parenthetical dashes never take commas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I would either leave out the comma before *but* or, if that bothers you, simply use different punctuation—such as parentheses.

---

Let's start from the simpler sentence and then add the extra information:

> I am a man, but I cannot endorse your claim.

So far, so good.

Now, we want to add ***a strong, burly man*** as parenthetical information:

> I am a man, ***a strong, burly man***, but I cannot endorse your claim.

While this is syntactically sound, the proliferation of commas makes it look a little odd. So, in order to deal with all of the commas, it can be rephrased in a few different ways:

> I am a man, ***a strong and burly man***, but I cannot endorse your claim.
> I am a man ***(a strong, burly man)***, but I cannot endorse your claim.
> I am a man—***a strong, burly man***—but I cannot endorse your claim.

---

The problem posed in the question is whether or not there needs to be a comma placed before *but*—something which would typically (although not always) be the case when there are two independent clauses.

Let's take the example with the parentheses:

> I am a man <s>(a strong, burly man)</s>, but I cannot endorse your claim.
> → I am a man, but I cannot endorse your claim.

Here, we remove all parenthetical information *including its punctuation*, and end up back at the original sentence.

---

Now, let's look at the version that uses parenthetical commas:

> I am a man, a strong and burly man, but I cannot endorse your claim.

This version also seems fine in long form. Yet, if we were to *actually* remove the optional information *and* its punctuation, we would end up with this:

> I am a man<s>, a strong and burly man,</s> but I cannot endorse your claim.
> → I am a man but I cannot endorse your claim.

Note that there is no comma—because it was removed. But I suspect nobody would think the long version is incorrect because of this.

When the extra information is taken out, we simply *don't* remove both commas. Depending on how you look at it, we either keep one of them or we remove both—and then add one back in again:

> I am a man<s>, a strong and burly man</s>, but I cannot endorse your claim.
> I am a man, <s>a strong and burly man,</s> but I cannot endorse your claim.
> I am a man<s>, a strong and burly man,</s> but I cannot endorse your claim.
>
> → I am a man, but I cannot endorse your claim.

---

In fact, you could make the claim that the second comma in the full sentence is playing a dual role. It's serving not only to terminate the parenthetical information but *also* to introduce the second independent clause.

This follows the same rule as when we end a sentence with an initialism:

> ✘ I live in the U.S.A..
> ✔ I live in the U.S.A.

Rather than repeat the period after *A*, we only use a single period. It serves a role in both the initialism *and* in the termination of the sentence.

The use of the comma has the same kind of dual role:

> ✘ I am a man, a strong and burly man,, but I cannot endorse your claim.
> ✔ I am a man, a strong and burly man, but I cannot endorse your claim.

We do not use two commas in row, but only a single comma.

---

With that in mind, let's look at the version of the sentence that uses dashes:

> I am a man—a strong, burly man—but I cannot endorse your claim.

I would argue that the second dash is, as with the single period after the initialism and the single comma after the parenthetical commas, serving a dual role.

It's not only acting to terminate the parenthetical information, but it's also standing in for the comma that would normally go before the conjunction.

Therefore:

> I live in the U.S.A ***[..]***
> → ✔ I live in the U.S.A.
>
> I am a man, a strong and burly man ***[,,]*** but I cannot endorse your claim.
> → ✔ I am a man, a strong and burly man, but I cannot endorse your claim.
>
> I am a man—a strong, burly man ***[—,]*** but I cannot endorse your claim.
> → ✔ I am a man—a strong, burly man—but I cannot endorse your claim.

However, if you don't like how that looks, then simply use parentheses for situations like this.

---

A final alternative is to not make the extra information parenthetical at all:

> I am a man—a strong and burly man, but I cannot endorse your claim.

Here, I've again replaced the comma between *strong* and *burly* with *and* (to avoid the appearance of too many commas). But the entire phrase *a strong and burly man* is no longer parenthetical; instead, it's actually *additional*.

This changes the meaning of the sentence very slightly (it's no longer optional information that can simply be removed), but that may be acceptable.