# Replacing a comma with a subordinate clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Can I add more information to this sentence

> To achieve efficiency and tangible results, motivation of the workers
>   is important as it can help them improve their performance and
>   happiness.

and make it like this without it being wrong grammatically?

> To achieve efficiency and tangible results**, which are critical in any
>   workplace,** motivation of the workers is important as it can help them
>   improve their performance and happiness.

If i remove the which clause, the sentence will only make sense when a comma is also added, like in the original sentence.

Comment: There's no reason why you can't do that. When you remove the *which* clause, you simply remove it and the first comma, but leave the second comma intact. You can think of the second comma in the longer version as serving two purposes at the same time: both ending the parenthetical and introducing the independent clause. If I understand your concern correctly, we would not use two commas in a row. (I address this at length, along with other punctuation, in answer to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/502472/291924) question.)

Comment: When you explained about removing only one comma and from your other answer in the link, I see how it works now. Thank you!